# Clean URLs Using forward slash '/' in to_param with Rails (3)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is this possible?

```
def to_param
  "#{id}%2F#{slug}"
end
```

This works in Chrome and Safari, but if Firefox you see the "%2F" in the address bar.  Is there a cleaner way?

Comment: Attempting to implement clean URLs in rails that use the format of "id/slug" rather than "id-slug"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is indeed an old post, but I want to build a bit on it.

If you don't want to have to handle an slug variable in your params, you really need to define that method to_param in your model

```
def to_param
  "#{id}/#{title}"
end
```

and set a route like so:

```
resources :posts, :id => /[0-9]+\/.+/
```

That way your link definition looks quite like a normal one:

```
link_to post.title, post_url(post)
```

Very simple: http://www.miguelsanmiguel.com/2011/03/17/slug-that-slash

Comment: is there anything in rails 3 that might make this break? I'm having trouble getting it running with your exact code.

Comment: BTW - It works great with a "-" or "_" in the `to_param` method, but breaks when I go for the "/" (I of course have to edit the regex accordingly)

Comment: First: the code above runs in Rails3. Second: having a slash in your slug (post title) is not a good idea since it represents a deeper level in a URL and it isn't compatible with nested resources, so you should substitute it somehow. Actually, we should do it with any [reserved URL character](http://www.blooberry.com/indexdot/html/topics/urlencoding.htm). I suggest something like: `def to_param; "#{id}/#{name_without_reserved_url_characters}"; end`. Great point!

Answer (score 3):

Ok I tried this just now you won't need this:

```
def to_param
  "#{id}/#{slug}"
end
```

In routes.rb (replace what you want with what you need)

```
match "/expenses/:id/:slug" => "expenses#show", :as => :expense
```

Your link_to should look like this now

```
= link_to "something", expense_url(:id => expense.id, :slug => expense.slug)
```

hope this helps a bit

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [Friendly ID](http://github.com/norman/friendly_id) -- it will eliminate the ID entirely and just use the slug.  It is Rails 3 compatible as well.

Answer (score 0):

maybe something like this can help you

```
match "/foo/:id", :to => redirect("/bar/%{id}s")
```

check out the section The "Redirect Method" in this article about rails3 and routes

http://www.engineyard.com/blog/2010/the-lowdown-on-routes-in-rails-3/